# How to insert into a system versioned table with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm getting classes for the tables in the DB as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.automap

eng = sa.create_engine(CONNECTION_URL)
Base = sa.ext.automap.automap_base()
Base.prepare(eng, reflect=True)
Session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=eng)

Table1 = Base.classes.Table1
```

In my case Table1 is [system versioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) which I understand sqlalchemy doesn't [explicitly support](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4797).

When running the following code:

```
t = Table1(field1=1, field2=3)
with Session() as session:
    session.add(t)
    session.commit()
```

I get the following error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'DBName.dbo.Table1'. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column. (13536) (SQLExecDirectW);

I understand this probably has to do with the `ValidTo` and `ValidFrom` columns

```
Table1.__table__.columns.keys()
# Column('ValidFrom', DATETIME2(), table=<Table1>, nullable=False)
# Column('ValidTo', DATETIME2(), table=<Table1>, nullable=False)
```

How do I tell `sqlalchemy` to ignore those columns during the insert statement?

**EDIT**

I'm guessing the below is the relevant part of the create statement?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    [TableID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    ...
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the sql "create table" scriptt?

Comment: I'm also farily "old school" when it comes to using python to write to a DB, in that I'll create the SQL string and then execute it within the script.
https://sqlhints.com/tag/insert-temporal-table/

Comment: added part of the create statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this code below working using a sqlalchemy.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer2
(  
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  StartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START 
               NOT NULL,
  EndTime   DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
              NOT NULL ,
  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)   
) 
WITH(SYSTEM_VERSIONING=ON (HISTORY_TABLE=dbo.CustomerHistory2))
```

If the StartTime / EndTime columns are **hidden** (which these arent't) then a value isn't needed in the insert statement you can add just the required. However the date columns in my table are required, so using default.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Customer2 VALUES (2,'Someone else', default,default)"

print(sql)

with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(sql)
```

Comment: interesting - that seems to be the catch - do you know of a pythonic / sqlalchemy way of doing this? (ie avoiding explicitly writing out the raw sql)

Comment: I tend to approach the python/data coding from the database point of view using the sql in a string (so printing helps debug). I should think "python" more often, but I generally write in sql first.

I think the issue here (with temporal) is that "default" is used as a database value, whereas I think python would see it as a variable to be assigned a value and you couldn't import it as "default" as that would be seen as a string...